# Sieve of Eratosthenes not working

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My computer basically crashes when I try to run this code.

Could someone please point out why?

I realize that resizing a list is not the most efficient way of doing this, but even typing in any number under *10* will yield nothing at all and makes [spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) or my computer crash.

My goal was to set up a class that I could store the instance of someone's number as so that I wouldn't have to run the function again if someone wanted to call the same number.

```
class eratosthenes(object):

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        count1 = 2
        self.lst = []
        while count1 <= b:
            self.lst.append(count1)
            count1+=1

    def sieve(self):
        self.count2 = 2
        while self.count2 < self.b/2.0:
            for i in self.lst:
                if i%self.count2==0:
                    self.lst.remove(i)
            self.count2+=1

a=raw_input("How far are you willing to go in this search for what you seek, young traveler?: ")
q = eratosthenes(a)  
print q.sieve()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for entry in lst:
    print(entry)
    lst.remove(entry)
```

You'd think that code would print the values 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.  Instead (under Python 3.6 on macOS Sierra) you get 1, 3, and 5.

Modifying a list as you're walking down it is a no-no.  And if you look in your `sieve` method, that's what you're doing.

Hope this helps!